# How to get unique list from a column then get its corresponding max value ignore #N/A using vba

Tags: excel, vba

My worksheet has certain columns starting from yield curve (column A, cell A4), term, term points, current quarter rate, previous quarter rate, variance, variance in %, currency, blank column, var tolerance flag, yc tolerance flag, variance in flag (column K), what i need is a unique list of unique ccy in column O4 using =unique(H:H) till last row and their corresponding max value in column P4 (=MAX(IF(ISERROR(L:L)=FALSE,IF(H:H=O4,L:L))) the formula should change the value of cell O4 row by row till the last row and at the end hard paste the values but before that the code should also calculate the value of column L in absolute terms using = abs(G4) till last row of column G. Here is what i have written so far, its working but not doing the right thing. it duplicates the first unique value to all the rows.

'''

```
Sub GetUniqueCurrenciesAndMax()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim uniqueCurrencies As Variant
  
    Dim maxCurrencyValues() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QRM_YC_QoQ_Checks")
   

  uniqueCurrencies = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(ws.Range("H:H"))
  ws.Range("O4").Resize(UBound(uniqueCurrencies) + 1, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(uniqueCurrencies)
  
  ReDim maxCurrencyValues(1 To UBound(uniqueCurrencies) + 1, 1 To 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(uniqueCurrencies) + 1
  maxCurrencyValues(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs(ws.Range("L:L"), ws.Range("H:H"), uniqueCurrencies(i, 1), ws.Range("L:L"), "<>#N/A")
  Next i
  ws.Range("P4").Resize(UBound(maxCurrencyValues, 1), 1).Value = maxCurrencyValues
  


End Sub
```

'''
[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `Dictionary` object to get the unique list and find the max value

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, ws as Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, lastRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QRM_YC_QoQ_Checks")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrData = ws.Range("H4:L" & lastRow).Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Not IsError(arrData(i, 5)) Then
            sKey = arrData(i, 1)
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                If arrData(i, 5) > objDic(sKey) Then
                    objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 5)
                End If
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 5)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' modify the location of output as needed
    ws.Range("O:P").ClearContents
    ws.Range("O6:P6") = Array("CCY", "Max Variance")
    ws.Range("O7").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
    ws.Range("P7").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.items)
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

*Update:*

> Question: can we also include a line to calculate the value of column L (L4:L) using the following formula , =abs(G4) the reference should be different in each row like G5, G6, G7 and so on

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, lastRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QRM_YC_QoQ_Checks")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrData = ws.Range("G4:L" & lastRow).Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Not IsError(arrData(i, 1)) Then
            arrData(i, 6) = Abs(arrData(i, 1))
            sKey = arrData(i, 2)
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                If arrData(i, 6) > objDic(sKey) Then
                    objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 6)
                End If
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 6)
            End If
        Else
            arrData(i, 6) = arrData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ' update col L with Abs(Gx)
    ' ws.Range("G4:L" & lastRow).Value = arrData
    ' modify the location of output as needed
    ws.Range("O:P").ClearContents
    ws.Range("O6:P6") = Array("CCY", "Max Variance")
    ws.Range("O7").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
    ws.Range("P7").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.items)
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: can we also include a line to calculate the value of column L (L4:L) using the following formula , =abs(G4) the reference should be different in each row like G5, G6, G7 and so on

Comment: Do you want to calculate `Abs(Gx)` on the fly with VBA or keep the result in L? How to populate the cell in col L if the cell in col G has error?

Comment: actually the code should start getting the values of column L by using the formula = ABS(G4) and so on for each row till last row , i need it on the fly

Comment: if any cell in column G has an error then it should be error in column L cell as well and that's fine

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: i will hard paste the values of column L like we have done it for column P, also try to sort the column P from largest to smallest